# Notification to resume activity (with data intact)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I've seen many questions in regards to this "issue" but there aren't any with an actual answer that works flawlessly.

In my app (fitness related) I issue a notification when the user leaves it during a workout so that he can quickly return to it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, WorkoutActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setClass(ctx, WorkoutActivity.class);
return new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(icon);
```

Now this works just fine. Thanks to the `Intent` flags the activity is resumed if it's up and running.

However the problem I'm seeing is that whenever the app has been in the background long enough and the OS decides to kill it; entering it through the notification will start a new instance of the activity - losing all data. Here are the two ways of re-entering the app after it being in the background, including the behaviour I'm looking for.

1. Press the notification. Problems arise here since the activity has been destroyed and the notification launches a new clean instance of it, without any data saved. **This is my problem...**
2. Press the launcher icon. You are then taken to the main activity of the app, and upon closing this you are taken to the destroyed version of the activity and it is restarted, with all state restored. **This is how I want it to work through the notification as well.**

Additionally I am saving all state in `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring it as per android standard with the `savedInstanceState` variable in `onCreate`.

Here's the relevant part of the manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name="workout.progression.ui.workout.WorkoutActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="workout.progression.ui.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WorkoutActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

And here's the root activity:

```
   <activity
    android:name="workout.progression.ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: So since you're using a notification the savedInstanceState variable is null?

Comment: onSaveInstanceState saves for configuration changes, but doesn't save you from the app being removed from memory completely. How do you persist your data?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I dont persist it until a workout is actually complete. However as #2 in the question the activity is able to restore the data, I just want to know how it can do it through a notification as well.

Comment: That's because the activity is still in memory. Once it is removed from memory, it is up to you to persist data.

Comment: @ianhanniballake But it isnt in memory, it can be killed and still restore its state (as long as I open it through the launcher).

Comment: Hitting the home button does not remove it from memory. Swiping it away from the Recents menu or force stopping it via settings will cause you to lose your in memory state with the same problem.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yep exactly. I hit the home button, swipe it away from recents and then I open it from the launcher (state restored) or through the notification (state lost).

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: @DavidWasser I dont really see what the manifest has to do with this (other than the launch mode) but I posted the relevant part of it for you.

Comment: The reason I ask about the manifest is to see how many activities you have, which is the "root" activity, and if you have specified `android:alwaysRetainTaskState`. If you ask for help you should be prepared to provide the necessary input. Otherwise you can just figure it out for yourself

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes of course, my manifest is quite long (its a large project) but I do not use alwaysRetainTaskState.

Comment: Please show the manifest entry for your root activity (the one that starts when your app is launched from the home screen) and the complete entry for the activity in question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent an activity from being killed by the OS, however, you can persist that data onto something else like SharedPreferences, a Database or to a file. Here's a guide on how to persist data: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Alternately, you can use a different launch mode such as 
singleTask:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

or singleInstance:

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always
>   the single and only member of its task.

This can however, mess a little with how your app and activity flow is handled.
References: 
[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)
[Activity Elements: Launch Modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: But onSaveInstanceState saves the state of the activity so that it can be recreated at a later time, f.x. if its destroyed by the OS. There shouldn’t be a need to persist values to a database or such. This exact functionality is present throughout my app, the only problem as I described earlier is that whenever the user re-enters the app through the notification, a new instance is created (even if the old one is in the stack somewhere).

Comment: This is why I updated the answer to include other launch modes. You can choose the one that suits your needs the best. This will allow you to handle any changes in onNewIntent(). also, I would advice to look if the activity is calling onNewIntent while in singleTop, my guess is that is is, since it's keeping the state for you.

Comment: No call to onNewIntent with SingleTop launchmode :( 
Singleinstance doesnt help much either unfortunately, and it really is not an option due to other reasons.

Comment: Well, to me it sounds like you need to change the launch mode. I don't know your requirements or constraints, but this will guarantee that no other either task or instance is created.

Comment: SingleTop sounds like the correct launchmode, however when the activity has been killed it will no longer be at the top of the stack (singletop would resume an activity if its already at the top of the stack) and a new instance would be created. Thus the same as it is now.

Comment: Messing with launch modes will not help you here. Your problem is that Android does not keep the state of "killed Activities" around forever.

Comment: @DavidWasser Are you sure about them not sticking around? Ive been able to open up my app days later with it restoring exactly everything the way it was.

Comment: Yes, Android will delete all state that it stores. This behaviour is, of course, also manufacturer and phone-specific. Also, if your app is storing the state itself, then of course it will behave as if Android is saving/restoring the state. For more information see the documentation for `android:alwaysRetainTaskState` at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always